# How to make a node a child of another node within the Scene editor?

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I know this question exists in many other forms but none of them have worked for me. I know you can programmatically add nodes as children of another, but I'd like to do that in the SceneKit editor so I can get the relative positioning correctly. I'd like to have it like in this picture, where "focus" is the parent of both "cursor" (which is the flat white text on the bottom) and "pointer" (which is the floating 3D object). Thank you in advance!

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to do this in the SceneKit editor.

1. Open the scene graph.
2. Drag the node you want to be child onto the node you want to be the parent.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much! Had no idea that thing existed at the bottom!!